# Golang HTTP Request types

Tags: go, go-http

The "net/http" golang package has [a response type](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Response) which I find confusing. It defines a member `Body io.ReadCloser` which requires an additional call to some form of an io writer to process. Why did the developers not choose to make the Body a `[]bytes` or a `string`? These seem like much more obvious, natural choices to me.

Comment: An io.Reader is the far more natural choice in Go as these interfaces _combine_. From a technical perspective using []bytes is bad as it doesn't allow any type of streaming.

Answer (score 4):

An HTTP response body is a stream of bytes on the network connection. The [io.Reader](https://godoc.org/io#Reader) type is Go's  representation of a stream of bytes.  The [Response.Body](https://godoc.org/net/http#Response.Body) field is typed as [io.ReadCloser](https://godoc.org/io#ReadCloser) which is an `io.Reader` with a `Close()` method.

An advantage of `io.Reader` over `string` and `[]byte` is that the application can stream through the response without loading the entire response in memory.

Use [io.ReadAll](https://godoc.org/io#ReadAll) to read the  [io.Reader](https://godoc.org/io#Reader)'s data to a []byte.

Here's a convenient helper function converting the `(*http.Response, error)` return values from the `net/http` functions to a `[]byte`:

```
func bodyBytes(r *http.Response, err error) (*http.Response, []byte, error) {
    if err != nil {
        return r, nil, err
    }
    b, err := io.ReadAll(r.Body)
    r.Body.Close()
    return r, b, err
}
```

Use the function like this:

```
 r, b, err := bodyBytes(http.Get("http://example.com"))
 if err != nil {
     // insert error handling here
 }
 // r is an *http.Response, with closed body
 // b is a []byte containing the body
```